# auto insert item to db by submitting a form when checkbox is checked no submit btn

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

So today i would like some helps for my homework. i have an exercise about submit form when checkbox is checked and auto insert value to database by without submit btn. Then the checkbox is uncheck i would like to delete value from database. Give me some example, please.

**this is my code**

*index.php*

```
<form action="create_fruit.php" method="post">
<input type ="checkbox" name="fruit" value = "apple">Apple</input>
<input type ="checkbox" name="fruit" value = "orange">Orange</input>
<input type ="checkbox" name="fruit" value = "banana">Banana</input>
```

*create_fruit.php*

```
<?php include "db.php"; if($_POST){$fruit = $_POST['fruit'];

$sql="INSERT INTO tblFruit(fruit_name) VALUES ('$fruit')";
$query = $connect->query($sql);

echo "Insert";} ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should handle onchange() of checkbox event in javascript.
In that you can send request to server whether to insert or delete value.
May this brief description helps you.

Answer (score 0):

you can do that easily with ajax.

HTML:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type ="checkbox" name="fruit" value = "apple" onClick="submit_data('apple');">Apple</input>
    <input type ="checkbox" name="fruit" value = "orange" onClick="submit_data('orange');">Orange</input>
    <input type ="checkbox" name="fruit" value = "banana" onClick="submit_data('banana');">Banana</input>
<form>
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function submit_data(val) {

        var fruit = val;

        if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
            ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }else{
            ajax = new ActiveObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
        }
        ajax.open(type, file_name, true);
        ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        ajax.send("fruit="+fruit);

        ajax.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if((ajax.readyState == 4)  && (ajax.status == 200) ){

                if(ajax.responseText) {
                    /* success: do something */
                    alert(success);
                }

            }
        };
    }
</script>
```

PHP (Separate file):

```
<?php 
    include "db.php";
    if(isset($_POST["fruit"])) {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO tblFruit(fruit_name) VALUES ('$fruit')";
        $query = $connect->query($sql);
        echo "Insert"; 
    }
?>
```

Comment: can you give me an example, please.

Answer (score 0):

you can use following code

```
<script>
    $('input[name="fruit[]"]').change(function(){
           var value = $(this).val();
           var url = "create_fruit.php"; 
           $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: url,
               data: "fruit="+value,        //POST variable name value
               success: function(msg){
                   console.log(msg);
               }
           }); 
     }); 
</script>
```